# Fullscreen Youtube (or other flash apps) in tab

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I have this question mainly about youtube video's, but extentable to any flash app that plays in fullscreen. Is there a possibility to make fullscreen not take over the entire screen, but just inside the tab where the video is loaded? Is there any addon or setting I can use to make this happen?

If other browsers (eg Chrome) do support this functionality, please feel free to reply!

Thanks in advance, Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty code for scratchpad or bookmarklet to view a youtube video as full page:

```
if(location.href.match(/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=(\w+)/)){
    location.assign(["http://www.youtube.com/embed/",RegExp.$1].join(""));
}
```

Note: Snippet omits encodeURIComponent and parsing query parameters, which you probably should implement if you're going to use it in an actual bookmarklet/userscript/addon.

Comment: Wonderfull, tried it out using the developer webconsole and works just like I want it too! Thanks for the reply :)